# Array JSON decoding in swift

Tags: json, swift, swiftui

I am trying to decode this json array and I got the following code to work, initially but it is a bit buggy.

the json is structured as following:

```
{
"prices": [
  [
    1595642361269,
    180.62508267006177
  ],
  [
    1596642361269,
    190.1
  ]
],
"market_caps": [
  [
    1595642361269,
    3322122955.6677375
  ],
  [
    1596642361269,
    3332122955.6677375
  ]
],
"total_volumes": [
  [
    1595642361269,
    590499490.5115521
  ],
  [
    1595642361269,
    590499490.5115521
  ]
]
}
```

my swift object is structured as:

```
struct MarketChart: Decodable {
    let prices: [[Double]]
    let market_caps: [[Double]]
    let total_volumes: [[Double]]
    
}
```

I dont think it is optimal but as the json doesn't have keys for the timestamps and values I was a bit confused on how to structure it.

the following is my playground code:

```
func getJSON<T: Decodable>(urlString: String, completion: @escaping (T?) -> Void) {
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        return
    }
    let request = URLRequest(url: url)
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        guard let data = data else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
        guard let decodedData = try? decoder.decode(T.self, from: data) else {
            completion(nil)
            return
        }
        completion(decodedData)
    }.resume()
}


struct MarketChart: Decodable {
    let prices: [[Double]]
    let market_caps: [[Double]]
    let total_volumes: [[Double]]
    
}

var priceArray: [Double] = []

print(priceArray)

getJSON(urlString: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin-cash-sv/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=1") { (data: MarketChart?) in
    if let data = data {
        for item in data.prices {
            priceArray.append(item.first!)
        }
    }    
}
print(priceArray)
```

I am trying to get all the values into an array and it did work initially but now just keeps printing an empty array. my end goal is to crate a graph of the values over time in a project and I did it successfully the first time but now I keep getting an error saying it can't get the value from an empty array.

my Xcode project file is as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftUICharts
import Combine

struct CoinGeckoBSVMarketChart: View {
    @State var jsonData = [MarketChart]()
    @State var priceArray = [Double]()
    @State var volumeArray: [Double] = []
    
    private let last24hpricesURL: String = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin-cash-sv/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=1"
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                LineView(data: priceArray)
                    .padding()
                
                Text("Reset")
                    .onTapGesture {
                        
                    }

            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            getJSON(urlString: last24hpricesURL) { (data: MarketChart?) in
                if let data = data {
                    for item in data.prices {
                        priceArray.append(item.last!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MarketChart: Decodable {
    let prices: [[Double]]
    let market_caps: [[Double]]
    let total_volumes: [[Double]]
}

struct CoinGeckoBSVMarketChart_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        CoinGeckoBSVMarketChart()
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
    }
}
```

any help with either improving the json object model or getting all the items in an array would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to print out the `priceArray` inside the completion block of `getJSON` method right after appending.

```
getJSON(urlString: "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/bitcoin-cash-sv/market_chart?vs_currency=usd&days=1") { (data: MarketChart?) in
    if let data = data {
        for item in data.prices {
            priceArray.append(item.first!)
        }
        print(priceArray)
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have any idea why my Xcode project is crashing I have updated the question to show the code for it

Comment: Hey @HenryHudson I'm not sure but, will try to help you out but why don't you ask it in another post because it's unrelated to array decoding in swift as the title suggests.

Comment: I have to wait a little bit stack overflow says but I will post it once I can

Comment: Oh yes, SO has the cool off time, so that people could try to figure it out by themself in the meantime. You can post the link in the comments and I'll surely try to help.

Comment: thanks @Frankenstein have edited this post to include the Xcode project file now at the end, I will also post the link once I am able.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124840/code-crashing-due-to-error-cant-remove-last-element-from-an-empty-collection